# Which kind of way to encourage users to leave feedback is better?

Tags: website-design

This question came into my head when I was browsing my LinkedIn profile. LinkedIn added a new feature - [Endorse](http://blog.linkedin.com/2012/09/24/introducing-endorsements-give-kudos-with-just-one-click/).

[image]

To my mind this was done very poorly because as I can see in my profile I have been endorsed by persons that know me but have not worked closely enough to know about my skills (I have checked profiles of my friend - same situation). And I have noticed that when I opened profile, annoying blue window showed and shifted content down. This windows contains randomly(?) added skills and suggested me to endorse profile's owner and fast way to close this windows - click yellow button (endorse).

My question is: how to possible to pay attention of users to new feature (and enforce to use it) if it isn't located on top of page and avoid big amount of trash in user's reaction? LinkedIn endorsement is prefect sample for this question.

Comment: Seems like a Zerply rip off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My initial thought would be to locate the 'endorsement section' on a non-scrolling side panel, rather than inline. That would allow the content to be easy to find since it would always be visible, and it would keep the important content in the scrollable main section from shifting down.

Comment: Non-scrolling side panel - is it something like to FB panel?